# Laravel QueryBuilder - Different result with `where()` and `whereRaw()` for the identical Query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm working on a laravel application Where I have two very similar `QueryBuilder` but producing different result in both conditions.

**Query 1:**

```
$ids = $this->model->leftJoin('feed', 'agents.identifier', '=', 'feed.identifier')
            ->whereRaw('feed.active <> agents.feed_status')
            ->pluck('id');

dd(count($ids)); // print 485236
```

**Query 2:**

```
$ids = $this->model->leftJoin('feed', 'agents.identifier', '=', 'feed.identifier')
            ->where('feed.active', '<>', 'agents.feed_status')
            ->pluck('id');

dd(count($ids)); // print 4259
```

I would like to know the key difference between these two QueryBuilder. Why is it producing different results, although it seems identical?

And which query returns the correct result? if I would like to find the records from agents where `feed_status` **is not equel to** `feed.active`.

Comment: I would guess that either the underlying data somehow is not the same, or maybe the model being used in your PHP for the `agents` table is not the same object in each case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seem I have got the clarification. Howevere I would like to share my R&D here. Incase if anyone else got the same problem.

I have printed the `raw query` and get `where()` seems consider the third parameter as `string` compare instead of `field` compare. That's why seems the result is different.

However when we run the query with `whereRaw()` it's treated this as table field comparision.

**Laravel Code:**

```
$ids = $this->model->leftJoin('feed', 'agents.identifier', '=', 'feed.identifier')
            ->whereRaw('feed.active <> agents.feed_status')
            ->pluck('id');
```

**MySql Query:**

```
"select * from `agents` left join `feed` on `agents`.`identifier` = `feed`.`identifier` where feed.active <> agents.feed_status"
```

**# where feed.active <> agents.feed_status**

**Laravel Code:**

```
$ids = $this->model->leftJoin('feed', 'agents.identifier', '=', 'feed.identifier')
            ->where('feed.active', '<>', 'agents.feed_status')
            ->pluck('id');
```

**MySql Query:**

```
"select * from `agents` left join `feed` on `agents`.`identifier` = `feed`.`identifier` where `feed`.`active` <> 'agents.feed_status'"
```

**# where `feed`.`active` <> 'agents.feed_status'**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the results were meant to be different.

As `where` method compares a column with a literal value

```
->where('table.column', 'cond', 'value')
```

If you are looking to make comparisons in two columns without using `whereRaw` method; you should instead use `whereColumn` method

```
->whereColumn('table1.column1', 'cond', 'table2.column2')
```